# aggregate data between two dates with two dataframes

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, group-by

Given I have the following DF,
Assume this table has all the sales rep and all the Q end dates in the last 20 years.

| Q End date | Rep | Var1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/31/2010 | Bob | 11 |
| 03/31/2010 | Alice | 12 |
| 03/31/2010 | Jack | 13 |
| 06/30/2010 | Bob | 14 |
| 06/30/2010 | Alice | 15 |
| 06/30/2010 | Jack | 16 |

I also have a table of transactions events

| Sell Date | Rep |
| --- | --- |
| 04/01/2009 | Bob |
| 03/01/2010 | Bob |
| 02/01/2010 | Jack |
| 02/01/2010 | Jack |

I am trying to modify the first DF so to have a column that aggregates the number of transactions that happened 12 month prior to the q end date per Qend per Rep

The result should look like this

| Q End end | Rep | Var1 | Trailing 12M transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/31/2010 | Bob | 11 | 2 |
| 03/31/2010 | Alice | 12 | 0 |
| 03/31/2010 | Jack | 13 | 2 |
| 06/30/2010 | Bob | 14 | 1 |
| 06/30/2010 | Alice | 15 | 0 |
| 06/30/2010 | Jack | 16 | 2 |

My table has 2000-3000 sales rep per Q for ~20 years and number of transactions per trailing 12m can range between 0-7k ish.

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df1["Q End date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Q End date"])
df2["Sell Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Sell Date"])

df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Sell Date").set_index("Sell Date")

df1["Trailing 12M transactions"] = df1.apply(
    lambda x: df2.loc[
        x["Q End date"] - pd.DateOffset(years=1) : x["Q End date"]
    ]
    .eq(x["Rep"])
    .sum(),
    axis=1,
)

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
  Q End date    Rep  Var1  Trailing 12M transactions
0 2010-03-31    Bob    11                          2
1 2010-03-31  Alice    12                          0
2 2010-03-31   Jack    13                          2
3 2010-06-30    Bob    14                          1
4 2010-06-30  Alice    15                          0
5 2010-06-30   Jack    16                          2
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I'm thinking if there is a faster way to do it. My data my be need to be reshaped for that though